# Return Shipping Methods in Store REST API

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api

Is there an API endpoint to return all shipping methods and carrier codes used in the store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, currently (When answered this question), there is no built-in API. We should create the custom one:

The most important thing is the class [`Magento\Shipping\Model\Config\Source\Allmethods::toOptionArray()`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/app/code/Magento/Shipping/Model/Config/Source/Allmethods.php#L45) will help us to get all the shipping methods or active methods.

`app/code/Vendor/Shipping/etc/webapi.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Webapi:etc/webapi.xsd">
    <route url="/V1/shipping/methods" method="GET">
        <service class="Vendor\Shipping\Api\ShippingMethodInterface" method="getShippingMethods"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="Magento_Sales::sales" />
        </resources>
    </route>
</routes>
```

app/code/Vendor/Shipping/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Vendor\Shipping\Api\ShippingMethodInterface" type="Vendor\Shipping\Model\ShippingMethod"/>
</config>
```

app/code/Vendor/Shipping/Api/ShippingMethodInterface.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Shipping\Api;

/**
 * Interface retrieving shipping methods
 *
 * @api
 */

interface ShippingMethodInterface
{
    /**
     * Get shipping methods
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getShippingMethods();
}
```

app/code/Vendor/Shipping/Model/ShippingMethod.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Shipping\Model;

use Magento\Shipping\Model\Config\Source\Allmethods;
use Vendor\Shipping\Api\ShippingMethodInterface;

class ShippingMethod implements ShippingMethodInterface
{
    /**
     * @var Allmethods
     */
    protected $allMethods;

    /**
     * ShippingMethod constructor.
     *
     * @param Allmethods $allMethods
     */
    public function __construct(Allmethods $allMethods) {
         $this->allMethods = $allMethods;
    }

    /**
     * Getting active shipping methods
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getShippingMethods() {
         return $this->allMethods->toOptionArray(true);
    }
}
```

Remember to create the module XML and registration file.

Comment: can u provide github/code link that not working for me